# Read .txt files without \n python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I am reading a .txt file from python. This is being used as a config file for my program.

The only problem is that when i use the `.readlines()` function, it returns a list of the text with "\n" when ever there is a new line. Is there a way to read the file without these at the end?

this would make adjusting variables based on the config file much easier.

Text file:

```
800
500
212,122,122
```

This is the code:

```
config = open("config.txt", "r")
config = config.readlines()
print(config)
```

output:

```
['800\n', '500\n', '212,122,122']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readlines` includes the line separator, which you don't need.

Just do:

```
config = [x.rstrip("\n") for x in config.readlines()]
```

or simply use `splitlines()` which is equivalent to `split("\n")`

```
config = config.read().splitlines()
```

Best way memory-wise would be to use the file iterator to avoid reading all the file at once (iterator also returns newline):

```
config = [x.rstrip("\n") for x in config]
```

As a side note, it's not very wise to overwrite your file handle variable name. Better use 2 different variable names for the handle and the list of lines and a context manager (`with open("xxx") as config:`) instead of `config = open(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
config = open("config.txt", "r")
config = config.read().splitlines()
print(config)
```

**Result** `['800', '500', '212,122,122']`